# How to access a variable from an ajax request in a Pug file

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm using Express with Pug to practice some stuff. I did a request to a website and got some information; that information is in an array but since that information can change I'm trying to iterate over it with Pug but I'm not sure on how can I get that variable outside of the pug file; I get errors pointing that I'm not declaring the variable in the right way; errors like "... is not defined" etc. If I try to declare it on the express file it doesn't work neither so I don't know if I should declare it on express so the Pug file can have access to it or something. I'm not sure on how to do this.

**Pug file**

```
div#information
        table
            tr
                th Health
                th Defense
                th Speed

            tr
                each val in // (What goes here?)
                    td= val
```

The array in the js file with the Ajax request has the name of `statArr`

**Express**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var request = require('request');

/* GET home page. */
router.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.render('index');
});

router.post("/", (req, res) => {
    res.send(req.body)
})

module.exports = router;
```

If more information is needed please let me know.

Comment: If you are doing the request on the client with ajax, you will have to manually fill out the dom once the request is complete. If you make the request on the server, you can pass the array through to the `pug` template by passing it after the template name in `res.render('index', {statArr})`. Also express exposes `res.locals` to the template so you could set it there as well and it would be passed through to your pug template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this for the server example.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var request = require('request');

router.get("/", (req, res) => {
  request('yourURLWhereYouGetData', function (error, res, body) {
       if (!error && res.statusCode == 200) {

        var statArr = body.statArr;

        res.render('index', { statArr });
       }
    })
});

router.post("/", (req, res) => {
    res.send(req.body)
})

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Thanks, I think that I will go for the server side request; I think it suits my needs better in this situation.